# How can I require at least one checkbox be checked before a form can be submitted?

Tags: html, css, validation, checkbox

I have a list of multiple check boxes. The user can check all of them, but at least one should be checked to allow form submission. How can I enforce that requirement?

```
<p>Box Set 1</p>
<ul>
   <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 1" required><label>Box 1</label></li>
   <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 2" required><label>Box 2</label></li>
   <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 3" required><label>Box 3</label></li>
   <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 4" required><label>Box 4</label></li>
</ul>
<p>Box Set 2</p>
<ul>
   <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 5" required><label>Box 5</label></li>
   <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 6" required><label>Box 6</label></li>
   <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 7" required><label>Box 7</label></li>
   <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 8" required><label>Box 8</label></li>
</ul>
<p>Box Set 3</p>
<ul>
   <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 9" required><label>Box 9</label></li>
</ul>
<p>Box Set 4</p>
<ul>
   <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 10" required><label>Box 10</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could use PHP to check if at least 1 of the check boxes is checked. You would probably also want to make sure your <input "name"> is different for each check box otherwise getting the return variable values might be tricky.

Comment: Had similar problem. Solved with: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37825072/1479143

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Here's an example using jquery and your html.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkBtn').click(function() {
        checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;

        if(!checked) {
            alert("You must check at least one checkbox.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
         <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Box Set 1</p>
        <ul>
            <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 1" required><label>Box 1</label></li>
            <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 2" required><label>Box 2</label></li>
            <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 3" required><label>Box 3</label></li>
            <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 4" required><label>Box 4</label></li>
        </ul>
        <p>Box Set 2</p>
        <ul>
            <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 5" required><label>Box 5</label></li>
            <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 6" required><label>Box 6</label></li>
            <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 7" required><label>Box 7</label></li>
            <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 8" required><label>Box 8</label></li>
        </ul>
        <p>Box Set 3</p>
        <ul>
            <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 9" required><label>Box 9</label></li>
        </ul>
        <p>Box Set 4</p>
        <ul>
            <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 10" required><label>Box 10</label></li>
        </ul>
        <input type="button" value="Test Required" id="checkBtn">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When box is not checked the error pops up. When box is not checked form does not submit?

Comment: Oops, when a box IS checked form does not submit

Comment: My example does not include a form tag or submit button. I'll leave that for you to do.

Comment: Jason, when no boxes are checked the error pops up. when  box is checked the form does not submit. Here is an example: http://www.tylerwebdesigns.com/test/ckbox.html

Comment: Finally got it! Had to add return false;
      if(!checked) {
        alert("You much check at least one checkbox.")
        return false;
      }

Comment: Please add that to your code so that if someone uses it in the future it will work/. Thanks a bunch! Jeff

Comment: Ok Jeff, I added the return false to prevent submitting a form.

Comment: @JasonR how would I check multiple groups of checkboxes using this script?

Comment: If you have multiple checkboxes to validate, use 
    checked = $("input[name='BoxSelect[]']:checked").length; 
in the javascript code.

Answer (score 46):

Make all the checkboxes `required` and add a `change listener`. If any one checkbox is ticked, remove `required` attribute from all the checkboxes. Below is a sample code.

```
<div class="form-group browsers">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="optiontext">Select an option</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="checkbox" name="browser" value="Chrome" required/> Google Chrome<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="browser" value="IE" required/> Internet Explorer<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="browser" value="Mozilla" required/> Mozilla Firefox<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="browser" value="Edge" required/> Microsoft Edge
    </div>
</div>
```

**Change listener :**

```js
$(function(){
    var requiredCheckboxes = $('.browsers :checkbox[required]');
    requiredCheckboxes.change(function(){
        if(requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked')) {
            requiredCheckboxes.removeAttr('required');
        } else {
            requiredCheckboxes.attr('required', 'required');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So simple and well understandable amongst all answers!

Comment: Are there any accessibility issues with having the form load with all inputs `required` by default when they're not actually all required?

Comment: Excellent thank you - works perfectly!  I did find that '.change' has now been deprecated so I replaced it with '.on' in case anyone has the same problem!

Comment: A in my opinion notable drawback of flagging all (or any of) checkboxes with the `required` attribute is that if the user attempts to submit the [invalid] form, the user agent (e.g. Chrome) may tell the user to "please check this box if you want to proceed", which may be a misleading message for some specific random checkbox, usually the first in the list. It's not that the user must select *that* (first) checkbox, it's just that they have to select one in the list. So the UX doesn't really match the design here.

Comment: @amn In that case, you can change the message shown when form is submitted and checkbox is not ticked..  you can change the text using `setCustomValidity(text)` in the `oninvalid` event. You can refer this link for changing the message https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361460/how-can-i-change-or-remove-html5-form-validation-default-error-messages

Comment: It won't help much -- the problem will be the user agent will flag some checkbox control as invalid, with invalid control notification shown next to the checkbox -- even if the notification text doesn't mention the specific checkbox, the user will be inclined to think it is _that_ checkbox they have to tick, which is the root of the problem here -- they don't have to check the checkbox that the user agent flags them as "invalid", they have to tick any in the group.

Comment: A better idea is to check for this condition with the `submit` event handler, and flag _some group element_ as valid/invalid according to whether any checkbox is ticked or not. Alternatively -- because there aren't any group controls that are well suited for this kind of validation (fieldset elements cannot be flagged as invalid, for instance), just produce your own markup that communicates invalid condition, foregoing use of `setCustomValidity`. Also don't forget to call `preventDefault` on the `submit` event if no checkboxes are ticked.

Answer (score 6):

```
<ul>
    <li><input class="checkboxes" name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 1" required><label>Box 1</label></li>
    <li><input class="checkboxes" name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 2" required><label>Box 2</label></li>
    <li><input class="checkboxes" name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 3" required><label>Box 3</label></li>
    <li><input class="checkboxes" name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 4" required><label>Box 4</label></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var checkboxes = $('.checkboxes');
    checkboxes.change(function(){
        if($('.checkboxes:checked').length>0) {
            checkboxes.removeAttr('required');
        } else {
            checkboxes.attr('required', 'required');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: this should be the correct selected answer

Answer (score 5):

This should have what you need, check out the jsfiddle at the bottom:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txt').val($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length);
    $('#txt2').val($("input[type=checkbox]").length);

    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
        $('#block').show();
        $('#block2').hide();
        if (checked > 0) {
            $('#block').hide();
            $('#block2').show();
            $('#txt').val(checked);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What happens if Javascript is disabled?

Comment: +1 because javascript/jQuery is easier/makes more sense than using PHP.  It's better to check before the form is even submitted.

Comment: ...but thinking of Dynelight's comment below, it'd be even better to use both so nobody can fool you if they fiddle with their javascript.

Comment: I do need to check on submit. There is lots of other data going and I would have to pass it back or they would have to start over.

Comment: How do I put an else in the js if none are checked and stop the form from sending?    if (checked > 0) {
  $('#block').hide();
  $('#block2').show();
  $('#txt').val(checked);
 }
else { check box not checked }

Answer (score 3):

The issue with the accepted solution above is that is does not allow for the else condition on form submit (if a box has been selected), thereby preventing form submission - at least when I tried it.

I discovered another solution that effects the desired result more completely IMHO, here:

[Making sure at least one checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787665/making-sure-at-least-one-checkbox-is-checked)

Code as follows:

```js
function valthis() {
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('myCheckBox');
    var isChecked = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
            isChecked = true;
        };
    };
    if (isChecked) {
        alert('At least one checkbox checked!');
    } else {
        alert('Please, check at least one checkbox!');
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qyE97/)

That code & answer by [Vell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1571812/vell)

Comment: add break after isChecked = true;

Answer (score 1):

For php, when you use checkboxes for multiple values, the name always ends with []. We can use this to make the solution a bit more generic. And, since I put my error message in a data-message-value-missing attribute, I use:

```js
$form.on('change', 'input[type=checkbox][name$="[]"]', e => {
    const $inputs = $('input[type=checkbox][name="' + e.target.name + '"]');
    const $targetInp = $inputs.filter('[data-message-value-missing]');
    if ($inputs.filter(':checked').length) {
        $targetInp.removeAttr('required');
        $form.find('label.error').html('');
    } else {
        $targetInp.attr('required', 'required');
    }
});
```

To make this work, set the data-message-value-missing and the required on only one (the last) input:

```
<ul>
   <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 1"><label>Box 1</label></li>
   <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 2"><label>Box 2</label></li>
   <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 3"><label>Box 3</label></li>
   <li><input name="BoxSelect[]" type="checkbox" value="Box 4" required data-message-value-missing="Select at least one"><label>Box 4</label></li>
</ul>
```

I excluded the code to handle the checkValidity(), etc. Seems beyond the scope of this question...

Answer (score 1):

I have read some other solutions to this, but they all suffer from a number of disadvantages, in my opinion, one or several of the following:

1. User agent will communicate about some *particular* checkbox when that checkbox or all checkboxes are marked up as required or when the checkbox is explicitly flagged as invalid with `setCustomValidity`. The result is confusing to the user as the user agent does its earnest clearly communicating to the user that the user must check *that particular* checkbox to proceed, which isn't what you'd want anyway -- you merely want the user to check *any* checkbox in the group, in the very least.
2. Flagging checkboxes as valid/invalid when checking and unchecking these is also a bit of a UX dead end -- you will need to validate the form containing these at submission anyway, even when the user hasn't touched any of the checkboxes once prior to attempting to submit the form -- how are you validating the form? Marking checkboxes as required to ensure at least one gets checked before form may be submitted gets you the aforementioned problem, again.

In light of these drawbacks, I, for one, have used the following approach:

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", ev => {
    if(!Array.prototype.some.call(checkboxes(), checkbox => checkbox.checked)) {
        tell_user_they_must_check_some_checkbox(); /// Instead of `setCustomValidity` which we can't use since we don't have a single particular checkbox to flag as invalid, just implement our own notification
        ev.preventDefault(); /// Prevent form submission -- the "submit" event only fires if the form was validated successfully in the first place, so it's up to us to stop the submission (according to our own validation constraints that cannot be expressed with `required` on some form controls).
    }
});
```

That's all I think there is to it. I left out selection of actual checkboxes since that's not the point the code is trying to illustrate, but you'll have to define the group of checkboxes you want to validate with the above by implementing `checkboxes`. It can be a generator function or simply one that returns the array or some HTML collection of these.

The important thing is that `setCustomValidity` can't meaningfully be used at all since there is no way to flag some group or at least contextually appropriate control of the form as invalid. If you find one, like some submit button, for example, the `tell_user_they_must_check_some_checkbox` reduces to a `setCustomValidity` call. You still need to prevent default because there won't be any checking of actually invalid controls *after* the "submit" event has been processed, that happens before, so we need to abort submission ourselves, if applicable.

As an exercise to the reader, you can implement grouping with some `data-` attributes or just grouping implicitly by containing the checkboxes where you want at least one in the group selected, in a `fieldset` (or even a `div` or whatever) and checking against those grouped -- like I said, which checkboxes you want to select for validating against the aforementioned condition, is entirely up to the form designer. You can even experiment with identical `name` for all grouped checkboxes, much like is done with radio buttons to good effect, but that may break traditional form submission (multiple checkboxes with the same name may not be serialized by the user agent into a POST request as you'd want them to be)

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this on a PHP level or on a Javascript level. If you use Javascript, and/or JQuery, you can check and validate if all the checkboxes are checked with a selector...

Jquery also offers several validation libraries. Check out: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

The problem with using Javascript to validate is that it may be bypassed so it is wise to check on the server too.

Example using PHP and assuming you are calling a PO

```php
<?php
if( $_GET["BoxSelect"] ) {
     //Process your form here
     // Save to database, send email, redirect...
} else {
     // Return an error and do not anything
     echo "Checkbox is missing"; 
     exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: What if they aren't using php? You should do _both_. Use javascript because it will give a faster validation response and save web server resources, but back it up with your server platform language because you can't trust the user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can check at least one checkbox is selected or not in different checkbox groups or multiple checkboxes.

Reference : [Link](http://34codefactory.blogspot.in/2017/12/at-least-one-checkbox-is-checked-from.html)

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-4">Check Box 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value=Male /> Male<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value=Female /> Female<br />

<label class="control-label col-sm-4">Check Box 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value=ck1 /> ck1<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value=ck2 /> ck2<br />

<label class="control-label col-sm-4">Check Box 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" value=ck3 /> ck3<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" value=ck4 /> ck4<br />

<script>
function checkFormData() {
    if (!$('input[name=checkbox1]:checked').length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("errMessage").innerHTML = "Check Box 1 can not be null";
        return false;
    }
    if (!$('input[name=checkbox2]:checked').length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("errMessage").innerHTML = "Check Box 2 can not be null";
        return false;
    }
    if (!$('input[name=checkbox3]:checked').length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("errMessage").innerHTML = "Check Box 3 can not be null";
        return false;
    }
    alert("Success");
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isAtleastCheckInputChecked(selector){
    
    var inputGroup = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    if(inputGroup == undefined){
        return false;
    }

    var isChecked = false;

    inputGroup.forEach(        
        function(currentValue, currentIndex, listObj) {
            if(currentValue.checked){
                isChecked = true;
            }
        }
    );

    return isChecked;
}

function validateForm(evt){

  validationStatus = isAtleastCheckInputChecked("input[name='desiredpositionchecks']");
  
  if(validationStatus){
    //looks good, can proceed for further procesing form data.
    document.querySelector("#validationStatus").innerText = "valid form";
    
  }
  else{
  //form is not valid
  document.querySelector("#validationStatus").innerText = "invalid form";
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
   
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md border-end col-sm-4 py-2">
                            <label for="firstName" class="form-label">DESIRED POSITION<sup style="color: red;">*</sup></label>
                              <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-feild form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="desiredpositionchecks" value="1" id="goalKeeperCheck" aria-describedby="desiredpositionchecks">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="goalKeeperCheck">
                                  GOAL KEEPER
                                </label>                                
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-feild form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="desiredpositionchecks" value="2" id="offensiveCheck" aria-describedby="desiredpositionchecks">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="offensiveCheck">
                                  OFFENSIVE
                                </label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-feild form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="desiredpositionchecks" value="3" id="defenseCheck" aria-describedby="desiredpositionchecks">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="defenseCheck">
                                  DEFENSE
                                </label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-feild form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="desiredpositionchecks" value="4" id="receiverCheck" aria-describedby="desiredpositionchecks">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="receiverCheck">
                                  RECEIVER
                                </label>
                                <div id="desiredpositionchecks" class="feedback invalid-feedback">Please select a valid feild.</div>
                              </div>            
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="col" id="validationStatus"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                            <button type="button" id="form-submit" name="form-submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="validateForm(event)">Check Validation</button>
                        </div>
                        
                            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one checkbox / radio group in your page, you can validate that at least one is checked by using the name attribute:

```js
$('#new-user-form').submit(function(e) {

  let roleChecked = $("input[name='NewUser.RolesArray']:checked").length;

  if (!roleChecked) {
    console.log("You must check at least one Role.");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="new-user-form" method="post">
    <div class="form-horizontal new-user">

        <div class="form-group">
            <h3 class="required">Roles</h3>
            <div class="roles h200">
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="NewUser.RolesArray" value="Academic Coordinator">
                        Academic Coordinator
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="NewUser.RolesArray" value="Human Resources">
                        Human Resources
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="NewUser.RolesArray" value="Support Technician">
                        Support Technician
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="NewUser.RolesArray" value="Student">
                        Student
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="NewUser.RolesArray" value="Director">
                        Director
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="NewUser.RolesArray" value="Administrator">
                        Administrator
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="NewUser.RolesArray" value="Finance">
                        Finance
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="NewUser.RolesArray" value="Manager">
                        Manager
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="NewUser.RolesArray" value="Modify Attendance">
                        Modify Attendance
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="NewUser.RolesArray" value="Attendance">
                        Attendance
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="NewUser.RolesArray" value="Teacher">
                        Teacher
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="required">Required</div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" id="create-button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery method which might be of interest to some people. Assuming that you want to treat your check-boxes as groups, just enclose them in a div and assign a class to the div, not the check-boxes as per this example:

```
<div id="my_checkbox_group_holder" class="checkbox-group required">
    <!-- manually set check-boxes or -->
    <!-- auto loaded by some means -->
</div>
```

Now, by targeting the div and the check-box property *checked*, jQuery can locate all the children in that div. Here, we have used the class names: **checkbox-group** and the conveniently named **required**. This will work:

```
let xChecked = $("div.checkbox-group.required :checkbox:checked").length;
if(xChecked > 0){
    alert('At least one checkbox is checked');
    return true;
}else {
    alert('NO checkbox is checked');
    return false;   //may be necessary to stop form submission
}
```