# Required fields in multiple checkbox and radio button

Tags: php, html

In html for radio button I have this:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female <br />
```

and for check list:

```
 <input name="checkboxvar[]" type="checkbox" value="dog" />Dog</td>
 <input name="checkboxvar[]" type="checkbox" value="cat" />Cat</td>
 <input name="checkboxvar[]" type="checkbox" value="rabbit" />Rabbit</td>
```

For the radio buttons how can I make them required and for the checkbox to take the result if the user select more than 1 values?

For the previous fields I use a submit button

```
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
```

Comment: Your questions isn't clear. To make them required you will need some sort of validation, either client-side using Javascript, or Server-side using PHP.

Comment: I use a submit button in html

Comment: Yes, but whether you use a submit button or not, what you are asking for is to validate the fields, and to do that you need more than HTML. If you want to run the validation before the data is submitted to your server, you will need to use Javascript to check the values before sending. Search for "javascript form validation" and see what you get.

Comment: @pjmorse yes that why I used as tag the php. If it is possible to have a notation if the field was checked it will return the value if not it will inform the user that he didn't check anything

Answer (score 0):

For making a radio button required, use the *required* tag (you only need add the *required* tag for one radio input per group):

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" required/> Male<br />
```

The `required` attribute is shorthand for `required="required"` or `required="true"` (the fact that its there constitutes a 'truthy' value, as does any (nonempty) string).

For making at least one of the checkboxes required: An answer has already been provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238368/multiple-checkboxes-at-least-1-required); this basically states that, given a `<button>` element with and id of `checkBtn`, the following code can help (with some of my comments on it):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // grabbing the button's element and adding an
    // onclick event to it
    $('#checkBtn').click(function() {
      // grabs all elements which are checkboxes and
      // are checked; if none are checked, the length
      // is zero; else, the length is a 'truthy' value
      checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
      // if no elements are checked
      if(!checked) {
        // error handling
        alert("You much check at least one checkbox.") return false;
      }

    });
});
```

Assuming that you want to detect the error upon the submit button's click; if you want to handle the error otherwise, you might want to clarify that (your answer *is* a tad vague).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

by using required attribute as follows:-

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" required />Male
```