# How to require at least one checkbox to be selected

Tags: javascript, html

Why is this script not working? Is it possible that I am targeting the attributes wrong? Result of this form should be that it cannot be submitted unless at least one checkbox is selected, however, user can select as many as they want.

```js
function valCheckbox() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("checkbox");
    var atLeastOneCheckBoxIsChecked = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
            atLeastOneCheckBoxIsChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (atLeastOneCheckBoxIsChecked === false) {
        alert("Please select at least one option.");
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="elq-field-style form-element-layout row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <label class="elq-label">Please select one or more options</label>
        <div>Choose as many as apply</div>
        <div id="formElement13">
            <div class="single-checkbox-row row">
                <input type="checkbox" name="option1">
                <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">Option 1</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="formElement14">
            <div class="single-checkbox-row row">
                <input type="checkbox" name="option2">
                <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">Option 2</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="formElement15">
            <div class="single-checkbox-row row">
                <input type="checkbox" name="option3">
                <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">Option 3</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="formElement16">
            <div class="single-checkbox-row row">
                <input type="checkbox" name="option4">
                <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">Option 4</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="formElement17">
            <div class="single-checkbox-row row">
                <input type="checkbox" name="option5">
                <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">Option 5</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="formElement18">
            <div class="single-checkbox-row row">
                <input type="checkbox" name="option6">
                <label class="checkbox-aligned elq-item-label">Option 6</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="formElement20" class="elq-field-style form-element-layout row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="Submit" class="sub-button" value="Submit" onclick="valCheckbox();">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This stack discussion has a helpful answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787777/13745258

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making sure at least one checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787665/making-sure-at-least-one-checkbox-is-checked)

Comment: @sebastian-ruehmann You should be able to flag a question as a duplicate of another question; I can't tell if you have or not, but just a heads up if you haven't.

Comment: Have you ever seen the 'checkboxes' variable value? Please write console.log(checkboxes) in your function at the very next of the 'checkboxes' declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Tagname checkbox so

```
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("checkbox");
```

Will return an empty array

You should use querySelectorAll and target input with type=checkbox

```
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
```

Comment: @S.Hesam What do you mean? The code above works with this update